# Recursively change some keys in a Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, translate, swift4.1

I have a dictionary

```
var dictionary: Any = ["det" : ["val" : "some","result" : ["key1" : "val1","key2" : "val2"],"key3" :["val1", "val2"]]]
```

and a mapping function below

```
func getMappedKey(_ key: String) -> String? {
    var mapping: Dictionary = [
        "key1" : "key3",
        "key2" : "key4",
        "det" : "data"
    ]
    return mapping[key]
}
```

Now I want to change some keys in the same dictionary using the mapping function above. So after the change, the dictionary should look like

```
["data" : ["val" : "some","result" : ["key3" : "val1","key4" : "val2"],"key3" :["val1", "val2"]]]
```

So for that I wrote a function below

```
func translatePayload(_ payload: inout Any) {
    if let _ = payload as? String {
        return
    } else if var payload = payload as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
        for (key, value) in payload {
            if let newKey = getMappedKey(key) {
                if let _ = payload.removeValue(forKey: key) {
                    payload[newKey] = value
                }
            }
            var nextPayload = value
            translatePayload(&nextPayload)
        }
    } else if let payload = payload as? Array<Any> {
        for value in payload {
            var nextPayload = value
            translatePayload(&nextPayload)
        }
    }
}
```

and when I call the function

```
translatePayload(&dictionary)
print(dictionary)
```

it does not change the keys in the same dictionary. Can someone please point out what is wrong with this code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine, you just updated the local variable instead of the parametric one because you used the same name. Just change the local variable `payload` to `dictionary` and `array` or anything else you like.

Here is the final code:

```
func translatePayload(_ payload: inout Any) {
    if let _ = payload as? String {
        return
    } else if var dictionary = payload as? Dictionary<String, Any> { // Here dictionary instead of payload
        for (key, value) in dictionary {
            var nextPayload = value
            translatePayload(&nextPayload)
            if let newKey = getMappedKey(key) {
                if let _ = dictionary.removeValue(forKey: key) {
                    dictionary[newKey] = nextPayload
                }
            } else {
                dictionary[key] = nextPayload
            }
        }
        payload = dictionary
    } else if let array = payload as? Array<Any> { // Here array instead of payload
        var updatedArray = array
        for (index, value) in array.enumerated() {
            var nextPayload = value
            translatePayload(&nextPayload)
            updatedArray[index] = nextPayload
        }
        payload = updatedArray // Assign the new changes
    }
}

translatePayload(&dictionary)
print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Even this does not work, it only changes the level 1/ top level keys and not after that...

Comment: @JayantJaiswal I have updated the answer. Please check again.

Comment: @JayantJaiswal The updated values were not inserted into the final dictionary.

Comment: It does not work if a key contains an array which again contains a dictionary... Try it for 
    ["det" : ["val" : "jay","result" : ["key1" : "val1","key2" : "val2"],"key3" :["val1", "val2"], "key5":[["key6" : "val6"], ["key7" : "val7"]]]]
and change key6 and key7

Comment: @JayantJaiswal Yes, It was the same case as in dictionary. Check the updated code.

Comment: There will be a slight change in you code in the array part, you need to replace the updated value at that index... Thanks anyways, its working now... You can update it there

Comment: @JayantJaiswal Yes, that you can add if you want to maintain the order.

Comment: @JayantJaiswal Updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170345/discussion-between-mukesh-and-jayant-jaiswal).

Answer (score 1):

Not really a direct answer to the question "what's wrong", but I'd go with something like:

```
let dictionary = ["det" : ["val" : "some","result" : ["key1" : "val1", "key2" : "val2"],"key3" :["val1", "val2"]]]

func getMapped(key: String) -> String {
    var mapping: Dictionary = [
        "key1" : "key3",
        "key2" : "key4",
        "det" : "data"
    ]
    return mapping[key] ?? key
}

func translate(payload:Any, map:(String)->String) -> Any {
    switch payload {
    case let value as String:
        return value
    case let value as [String:Any]:
        return value.reduce(into:[String:Any]()) {
            $0[map($1.0)] = translate(payload: $1.1, map:map)
        }
    case let value as [Any]:
        return value.map { translate(payload: $0, map:map) }
    default:
        fatalError("Unknown data type")
    }
}

let output = translate(payload: dictionary, map:getMapped(key:))
```

To really take advantage of the functional spirit of Swift.